# Updating the button type based on boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I'm wondering is it possible to update the button `type` between `"submit"` & `"button"` based on a boolean value: `form?.hasErrors)`

Here's my code:

```
    const btnType = () => {
      if (form?.hasErrors) {
        return "submit";
      }
      return "button";
    };

    return (
      <>
          <StyledButton
            onClick={!form?.hasErrors() ? handleShowModal : undefined}
            type={btnType()}
          >
            Search
          </StyledButton>
   );
```

I basically just want to ensure that if the form has errors, that the button type is set to "submit" and if not, it will be set to "button" (default).

Comment: Why not set the form validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want this. But i think you can use this.

```
  <StyledButton
    onClick={!form?.hasErrors() ? handleShowModal : undefined}
    type={form?.hasErrors() ? "submit": "button"}
  >
    Search
  </StyledButton>
```